# EmguCV equivalent to Java mat.put(i, 0, mv)

Tags: emgucv

I'm trying to convert a Java class to a C# one using EmguCV. It's for a class in Unsupervised Learning. The teacher made a program using OpenCV and Java. I have to convert it to C#.

The goal is to implement a simple Face Recognition algorithm.

The method I'm stuck at:

```
Mat sample = train.get(0).getData();
mean = Mat.zeros(/*6400*/sample.rows(), /*1*/sample.cols(), /*CvType.CV_64FC1*/sample.type());
        
// Calculating it by hand
train.forEach(person -> {
    Mat data = person.getData();
    for (int i = 0; i < mean.rows(); i++) {
        double mv = mean.get(i, 0)[0]; // Gets the value of the cell in the first channel
        double pv = data.get(i, 0)[0]; // Gets the value of the cell in the first channel
        mv += pv;
        mean.put(i, 0, mv); // *********** I'm stuck here *********** 
    }
});
```

So far, my C# equivalent is:

```
var sample = trainSet[0].Data;
mean = Mat.Zeros(sample.Rows, sample.Cols, sample.Depth, sample.NumberOfChannels);

foreach (var person in trainSet)
{
    var data = person.Data;
    for (int i = 0; i < mean.Rows; i++)
    {
        var meanValue = (double)mean.GetData().GetValue(i,0);
        var personValue = (double)data.GetData().GetValue(i, 0);
        meanValue += personValue;

    }
}
```

And I am not finding the put equivalent in C#. But, if I'm being honest, I'm not even sure the previous two lines in my C# equivalent are correct.

Can someone help me figure this one out?

Comment: Do you want to find the equivalent to `put` or you are satisfied with anything similar that will do the job?

Comment: Something similar would be enough.

Comment: What is the type of `trainSet` - or `train` in Java code?

Comment: Trying to detect faces. So, it's bits from a picture

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it like this:

```
Mat sample = trainSet[0].Data;
Mat mean = Mat.Zeros(sample.Rows, sample.Cols, sample.Depth, sample.NumberOfChannels);
foreach (var person in trainSet)
{
    Mat data = person.Data;
    for (int i = 0; i < mean.Rows; i++)
    {
        double meanValue = (double)mean.GetData().GetValue(i, 0);
        double personValue = (double)data.GetData().GetValue(i, 0);
        meanValue += personValue;
        double[] mva = new double[] { meanValue };
        Marshal.Copy(mva, 0, mean.DataPointer + i * mean.Cols * mean.ElementSize, 1);
    }
}
```